# My thermostat and heating system was working fine but the batteries read low power

Tags: thermostat

So my Honeywell non WiFi Thermostat was working fine except for the low battery signal in the top right-hand corner. We took the face off of the thermostat of course shutting the Heat and fan off before doing so replace the batteries and it seems to be working wonderful as far as the lights turning on and all the options working but now the heat will not go on and it is close to 55 degrees in my house and going to do nothing but drop for the rest of the night. Any suggestions? Help me please? Getting cold

Comment: try turning everything off and back on.

Comment: What happens when you jumper R and W at the thermostat base?

Comment: I tried on and off a few times, no heat

Comment: Three-phase idk what that means, how do I do it?

Comment: Are you using rechargeable batteries? They provide about 1.2v, whereas alkalines and lithiums provide about 1.5v.

Comment: I find new lithium to be 1.81 V.  I have wondered if this would be too high for some electronics which specify alkaline, but evidently designers want users to be able to treat lithium and alkaline as interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the model there is sometimes a very small reset button that needs to be pushed after the batteries are changed. Usually about 1/16” round. Not all thermostats have this though. It would be under the cover somewhere. I have also had similar problems with cheap batteries particularly Costco Kirkland batteries even brand new. I have never had problems with Duracell or Energizer